# Getting a z-index problem in jQuery + swfupload

Tags: jquery, z-index, swfupload

I'm using jQuery + swfupload.

When displaying a jQuery dialog, the swfupload-button always is on top and is overlapping the dialog window. I've already tried increasing the z-index of the dialog but didn't help.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Please set   button_window_mode property to transparent

```
button_window_mode: "transparent",
```

This problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to make the button position relative when setting the z-index?

Comment: the button is part of my gui, so the gui + the button have position:absolute - is there an issue about it with swfupload?

Comment: If you have position:absolute you should be allright.. I have had this problem myself, just dont remember how I solved it.. :\ Have you tried setting z-index and position on the swfupload object also?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, a jquery button was on top of a popup menu no matter what z-index I set the menu to. Changing position:relative solved it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
`button_window_mode: "transparent",`
then in syles add z-index to class .swfupload (lower then your popup has)